# Exception when starting a MvvmCross Uwp app: "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, uwp

I am trying to use MvvmCross to create a Windows Universal App, with the latest UWP bits (RTM).  In App.xaml.cs, when I attempt to run -

```
var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
start.Start();
```

I get a "System.AccessViolationException" -

```
Message: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
```

I've created a sample project to reproduce the problem, it contains -

- A Portable Class Library (Test.NewCore), which targets ".NET Framework 4.6" and "Windows 10".
- A "Universal Windows" app (Test.Uwp), which targets "Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)"
- I am using the latest nuget pre-release packages, "MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta3" and I believe I set it up properly (I looked at the examples here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/4.0/nuspec

You can download the test project here: http://1drv.ms/1G6w2m3

The full stack trace is below -

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.MvxWindowsViewPresenter.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.MvxWindowsMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel[TViewModel](IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle, MvxRequestedBy requestedBy)
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxAppStart`1.Start(Object hint)
       at Test.Uwp.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
  InnerException:
```

I am using Windows 10 RTM and Visual Studio 2015 RTM, no beta bits (except for MvvmCross).

What am I doing wrong?

I absolutely love MvvmCross and I'm beginning to port an existing Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 solution to Uwp - just doing some exploratory research on using the latest MvvmCross bits with Uwp.

Thanks for any help!
@ehuna

Comment: Could you put up the test project in a Github repo? That would make it easier to look at.

Comment: Ok, I added it here: https://github.com/ehuna/MvvmCross.Test.Uwp

Comment: Hey @ehuna to be honest I've tried changing your github repo, but was also unable to get it up and running. So maybe we could work backwards? I've added a working UWP version on my github https://github.com/Depechie/MvvmCrossUWPSplitView maybe you could take that one as your base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view that you are using is not correct and the AccessViolation that you get is - admittedly - no help at all. The problem seems to be that the runtime does not find the View that you specified and crashes with an obscure exception.

The TestView.xaml looks like

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="Test.Uwp.Views.View1"
    ...
```

but it should be

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="Test.Uwp.Views.TestView"
```

Respectively your TestView.xaml.cs looks like

```
public sealed partial class TestView : MvxWindowsPage<TestViewModel>
{
    public TestView()
    {
    }
}
```

but it should look like this

```
public sealed partial class TestView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public TestView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then everything will work fine. Interesting insight that I gained: `MvxWindowsPage<TestViewModel>` does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found, which may be different.
I create a UWP app (project1), add a UWP library (project2), and project1 reference project2.
In the library add a page. In project1 app.xaml.cs, change rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments) to rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Project2.MainPage), e.Arguments) so that it navigate to the page in project2.
Run and got the exception.
Workaround:
In project1 app.xaml, add the following to create an instance of the page (as a resource, which doesn't matter):

```
xmlns:project2="using:project2"
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<project2:MainPage x:Key="MainPage"></view:MainPage>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Run the app, it works.
So looks like the reason for the exception was caused by the page in the other project is not instantiated yet. If you instantiate it in app.xaml, it works.